# What is schmant?

Tags: ant, build

Do anybody know or heared from schmant?
See
http://www.stevevandermerwe.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/build-system-evolution13.png

The picture mention schmant as an ant variant without xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.schmant.org/

Took about 3 seconds to Google.

> Schmant provides an environment for running build scripts and a set of
>   tools (tasks) that the scripts can use. Schmant can, and will probably
>   mostly, be used for building Java applications. The immediate goal for
>   Schmant is to be comparable to Apache Ant in features, but nicer and
>   easier to work with.

Comment: Perfect, i also googled it but could not found.
I searched after 'schmant' 'ant' 'build' 'tool'... I got many other not relevant hits (with google.de).

Comment: First hit for "schmant" for me on `google.com`, 5th on `google.de`. It's probably because Google corrects 'nt' to 'ndt' by default on the German site.